# Rails has_many relationship where the "many" side can be of a different Type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to use ActiveRecord to model the following case scenario:

> I have a User that has many Favorites, That Favorite can be either a
>   Profile or a Group.

The Relationships would be something like this:

[image: models]

When I access the Favorites a User has; as in...

```
> user.favorites
```

I should get an Array back that contains Profile and/or Group ActiveRecord Objects.

```
[#<Profile id:1 ... >, #<Group id ... >, #<Profile ...>, #<Group ...>]
```

Is this possible? What is the **Rails-way** to do this?

Thank you, and Kind Regards,

Comment: Check out polymorphic associations: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Polymorphic+Associations

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Polymorphic Associations` as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favorites
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :favoriteable, polymorphic: true
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :favorites, as: :favoriteable
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :favorites, as: :favoriteable
end
```

For detailed explanation with example: Read [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) in Rails Official Guide.

Comment: Hi!, Kirti Thorat, thanks for the reply. Are you sure this works? Only the User is supposed to have the has_many :favorites macro activated. How does this work? could you explain your suggestion a bit further?

Comment: Thank you, your answer is still a bit obscure to me, could you please explain to me, How do you actually use it? Thank you Kirti

Comment: I would recommend you read about `Polymorphic Associations`. See link in my answer.